# NHibernate [Min(x)] that does greater than and not greater than or equal to?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate Validators, like:

```
[Min(Value = 1)]
public double SomeValue { get; set; }
```

And this ["built in constraints" table](http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx). All the constraints seem to be "included," e.g., greater than or *equal to*, less than or *equal to* ... I want the value to be the limit and not included. Is there anywhere to do this?

I suppose I could do the following:

[Min(Value = 1.1)]

But I'd rather not, as there's always going to be an infinitesimal between that value and the limit. I realize that if I use, say, a double, you can't keep going 1.0000001, but I'd rather not use the double's absolute limit, it'd make the attributes messy.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As your property is an `int`, it will never be 1.1, so you could do `[Min(Value=2)]`</strike>

From the reference, looks like you'll have to write your own validator. Doesn't look too difficult though.

Comment: Oops, in my head I was thinking double, changed it to double.

Comment: @chum - changed my anser then, seeing as you changed the question ;)